# A Theorem on Skew-Symmetric Bilinear Forms in Hoffman and Kunze's Book

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, bilinear-form

On pg. 377 in Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*(Second Edition) Theorem 6 reads:

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a subfield of the field of complex numbers, and $f$ be a skew symmetric bilinear form on $V$. Then the rank $r$ of $f$ is even, and if $r=2k$, then there is an ordered basis for $V$ in which the matrix of $f$ is the direct sum of the $(n-r)\times (n-r)$ zero matrix and $k$-copies of the $2\times 2$ matrix
>   $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 1\\
> -1 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

**My question** is whether or not the theorem is true if the base field of $V$ is just any field, not necessarily a subfield of the field of complex numbers.

I couldn't find any place in the proof where anything special about the base field was assumed.

Thanks to Gregory Grant for suggesting a correction.

Comment: See item 3.7 b) page 107 in the book Linear Algebra and Geometry by Kostrikin and Manin.

Comment: Thanks. The page talks about symplectic forms, which is a special type of skew-symmetric bilinear form. I don't see how this answers the question. At least not directly.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Are you sure you are quoting it right?  In my copy of Hoffman and Kunze it says "over a subfield of the field of complex numbers".  Not just "over the complex numbers".

Comment: If the characteristic of the field is not equal to 2 then for any skew-symmetric matrix $G$ we can find an invertible $A$ such that $AGA^t$ has this format.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Ah! you are right. Still, my question remains (essentially).

Comment: I imagine it remains true for any characteristic zero field, do you need it more generally than that?

Comment: I really don't need it right now. Was just curious why wouldn't H&K do it more generality if it is just as simple to do it in more generality.

Comment: @Daniel So the theorem is true for all fields with characteristic not 2. Do you know that it fails for characteristic $2$ field?

Comment: I assume "skew-symmetric" means that it sends $\left(x, x\right)$ to $0$ for all $x$ (since otherwise this result surely does not hold in characteristic $2$). For the proof in any characteristic, see (5.3) in Keith Conrad's *Bilinear forms* ( http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf ). His matrix is not the same as yours (which is closer to your (5.1), just with more zeroes), but is easily seen to be equivalent under a permutation of the basis elements.

Comment: @darijgrinberg The condition that $(x, x)=0$ for all $x$ means that the form is alternating. Skew-symmetry means that $(x, y)=-(y, x)$ for all $x$ and $y$. Thus every skew-symmetric form is alternating but not conversely.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: Then your claim is clearly not true in characteristic $2$, because the standard scalar product is skew-symmetric in this sense.

Comment: If the characteristic is 2 then $-1=1$, thus skew-symmetric is symmetric.  In this case this theorem is false, because it would imply that every symmetric matrix has even rank, which is not true in characteristic 2. The idea to prove this thm (when the characteristic is not 2) is to perform row reduction and column reduction simultenously. For example if $E$ is an elementary matrix then you must do $EGE^t$. You must repeat this until you obtain the desire shape.

Comment: Thank you both of you. This solves my issue.